# Find files where the first line is one word or less

Tags: bash, shell, awk, command-line, terminal

I am on Mac Os 10.14.6 and have a directory that contains multiple files. I would like to print out a list of files where the first line is one word or less.

How can I do this?

---

**Steps I have tried:**
awk has a function that can be used to count words:

```
awk '/^.+\|\w+ \|/'
```

This would be used to find all lines that contain one word.
However, I am not sure how to limit it to the first line of every file.

Comment: Only GNU awk would recognize `\w` as shorthand for the POSIX `[[:alnum:]_]`. Is that really what you mean by `word`, though, or do you mean contiguous sequence of any non-space characters (as would be matched by the answer you accepted) or something else?

Comment: By the way, the script you posted definitely would not "find all lines that contain one word", instead it would find lines that contain any one or more characters followed by a `|` character followed by (in gawk) one or more alphanumeric-or-underscore characters (or a `w` character in non-gawk) followed by a blank char followed by a second `|` followed by zero or more characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you please try following, I am using `nextfile` option of GNU `awk` which will help us to save cycles/time since once we check very first line of Input_file we need not to read complete Input_file then.

```
find '/your_path/' -type f -exec awk 'FNR==1{if(NF<=1){print FILENAME};nextfile}' {} \+
```

Point to be noted here is `awk`'s field separator is used as space(default of `awk`) here.

---

---

OR in case you don't have `nextfile` option in your `awk` try following then, where I am exiting after reading very first line which will save our cycles and will NOT read whole file after checking 1st line.

```
find '/your_path/'-type f -exec awk 'FNR==1{if(NF<=1){print FILENAME};exit}' {} \;
```